# Regexp strings with specific characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, special-characters, regexp-like

I would like to create a query where I select all records which may contain letters, digits and special characters from group of 3 special characters: `/` `"` `,`

I've tried `'[0-9a-zA-Z(\-\/\")]'` but something like `'a+'` works

Comment: What do you mean by "may"? Do you want to select all strings that contain at least one letter, or at least one digit, or at least one of the three punctuation marks? Or do you want the strings that do **not** contain **anything else**? In any case, if you are using a language other than English, you would do much better with `[:alpha:]` than using `a-zA-Z` - accented characters may or may not fall in those ranges, but `[:alpha:]` catches all letters. And `[:alnum:]` catches all letters and digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (-- valid values
  3     select 'Little12'     from dual union all
  4     select 'Foot/15'      from dual union all
  5     select '"London",UK'  from dual union all
  6     -- invalid values
  7     select '25+ miles'    from dual union all
  8     select 'me@gmail.com' from dual
  9    )
 10  select col
 11  from test
 12  where regexp_like(col, '^[a-zA-Z0-9/",]*$');

COL
------------
Little12
Foot/15
"London",UK

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z/",]+
```

Comment: Forward slash is not a special character in POSIX ERE regular expressions, which is what Oracle follows. (I am not aware of it being a special character in other regexp dialects either.) In addition, in POSIX ERE regular expressions, there are only a very small number of special characters in a character class, and they cannot be escaped anyway.

Comment: @mathguy You're right, it's a special character in JavaScript used for delimiting the regex expression. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "...there are only a very small number of special characters in a character class, and they cannot be escaped anyway". How come they cannot be escaped?

Comment: They cannot be escaped in a character class (what the POSIX standard calls "bracket expression" - an expression in square brackets, which matches exactly one character). The only special characters are `^` for negated character class, `-` for range, and `]` for terminating the bracket expression. They can't be escaped - if they need to represent themselves (rather than to have the special meaning), they must be placed where the special meaning doesn't make sense. For example, `]` would need to be the first character in the expression. `-` can be first or last. Etc.